# What does "head the bill" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does this phrase in the song [Wow - Kate Bush](http://google.com/search?q=Wow+Kate+Bush) mean?

> We're all alone on the stage tonight.
>   We've been told we're not afraid of you.
>   We know all our lines so well, uh-huh.
>   We've said them so many times:
>   Time and time again,
>   Line and line again.
>
> Ooh, yeah, you're amazing!
>   We think you're incredible.
>   You say we're fantastic,
>   **But still we don't** ***head the bill.***
>
> Wow! Wow! Wow! Wow! Wow! Wow! Unbelievable!

Comment: Note that "head the bill" and "foot the bill" have nothing to do with each other. To "foot the bill" is to pay the whole cost of a large purchase.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's usually [*top the bill*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=topped%20the%20bill%2Cheaded%20the%20bill&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctopped%20the%20bill%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cheaded%20the%20bill%3B%2Cc0) ([***bill = billing = billboard***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/billboard) = a flat surface or board, usually outdoors, on which large advertisements or notices are posted.

To *top the billing* literally means to be listed at the top of the advertising posters (as the most important of several attractions), but it can be used figuratively. Note that in some contexts (bands at a concert, actors in a movie, etc.) the alternative sequence *order of appearance* may used instead of *importance*. Rarely, you may come across ***head*** the bill (but not, I think, ***top*** the bill) to mean *be listed first in the promotional material because you're the first act to go on stage*.

Comment: I've seen "headline artist/etc" or "headliner" to refer to the most important performer more often than anything with top in it.  Is top more commonly used in the UK?

Comment: *And tonight Mr Kite is topping the bill* @DanNeely.

Comment: @TRiG: Ah, right! I forgot [that one!](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/beatles/beingforthebenefitofmrkite.html) :) But perhaps I might regret that smiley in a few hours if the [earworm](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/earworm) is still with me.

Comment: @Dan: As you'll see from [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=topped+the+bill%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cheaded+the+bill%3Aeng_us_2012%2Ctopped+the+bill%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cheaded+the+bill%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctopped%20the%20bill%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cheaded%20the%20bill%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctopped%20the%20bill%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cheaded%20the%20bill%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0), *topped the bill* is significantly more UK than US.

Comment: ...but I think all those variants *(head/top, bill, billing, billboard)* are getting a bit "dated". As you say, ***headlining*** is the "in" term these days (everywhere, I suspect). Not that it would have worked in Kate Bush's song (where *"But we still don't headline"* would probably be taken to mean *"We don't make the **newspaper** headlines"*).

Comment: You could be "top *of* the bill", though.

Comment: @Ollie: Sure. But as [this Googlefight shows](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=%22are+headlining%22&word2=%22are+top+of+the+bill%22), you're much more likely today to be ***headlining*** than ***top of the bill***. Here's [another supporting chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+headlining%2Cis+top+of+the+bill&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20headlining%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20top%20of%20the%20bill%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was really only responding to your "not top the bill". Top can be used for head, but the phrase is just restructured slightly.

Comment: This must be regional or something.  I've often hear "*head the bill*", but almost never "*top the bill*".

Comment: For what it's worth, historically bills aren't *only* attached to billboards. There was also such a thing as "handbills", now called flyers/leaflets/mailers/whatever. Since the "bill" *is* the advertisement or notice, it seems likely to me that "heading the bill" derives directly from the bill itself, not from the billboard that the bill was displayed on.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't [head the bill](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/bill_5) you are not the featured performer ( in a promotion sense)!